How to make a phone call on locked iPhone?
A toddler picked up my iPhone 13 (locked, unlock possible by 8 digit PIN or Face ID) and after just a minute made a phone call to one of the often called contacts.
How is that possible?
I have almost everything (that is possible) disabled on the lock screen. Siri is off.
iOS version is 17.5.1 (17.6.1 is out, but auto update did not install it yet)
10 minutes later another kid took the (locked again) phone and accessed the clock (alarm) settings.

How is it locked? Biometric or PIN? If it's the latter maybe they know the PIN.

Is the toddler named "Damian"?

@SteveChambers I added that information to the question. They can’t count and guessing 8 digits of pin is more or less impossible.

How old are the toddlers? They don't need to know how to count to mimic you typing the code, but it seems unlikely. Did you hold the phone in front of their face to see whether it unlocks?

Ha ha. I checked and it does not unlock. As I was present when this happened, maybe the camera caught my face and unlocked the phone.

If you swipe down from the upper right corner of the iPhone lock screen it will invoke Control Center. Perhaps this is how?

@SteveM No, there is no Control Center. As said, I have disabled almost everything possible on the Lock Screen.
